# Eclipse Plugin Creating a IJavaLineBreakpoint programmatically does not show method info in Breakpoints view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating a Eclipse plugin and I'm trying to create JavaLineBreakpoint using JDIDebugModel.

However, when a line breakpoint is created from the Java editor, it displays the Class name, the line number and the method name as the following image:

[image]

When the line breakpoint is created in the plugin the method name is replaced by the class name as follows:

[image: breakpoint create in the editor]

The following is the code used to create the breakpoint.

Thank you.

```
IBreakpoint[] breakpoints = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getBreakpointManager().getBreakpoints();
if (breakpoints.length == 0) {
    return null;
}

IJavaLineBreakpoint oldBreakpoint = null;
for (int i = 0; i < breakpoints.length; i++) {
    IBreakpoint breakpoint = breakpoints[i];
    if (breakpoint instanceof IJavaLineBreakpoint) {
        oldBreakpoint = (IJavaLineBreakpoint)breakpoint;
        break;
    }
}
if (oldBreakpoint != null) {
    Map newAttrMap = null;
    IResource resource = null;
    try {
        IMarker marker = oldBreakpoint.getMarker();
        if (marker != null && marker.exists()) {
            newAttrMap = marker.getAttributes();
            resource = marker.getResource();
        }
    } catch (CoreException ce) {
        Activator.logError("SinfoniaCloudBreakpointItem - Contructor - Marker attributes not found", ce);
    }
    int lineNumber = -1;
    try {
        lineNumber = (Integer)newAttrMap.get(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER);
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
    }
    try {
        JDIDebugModel.createLineBreakpoint( 
                resource,
                oldBreakpoint.getTypeName(),
                lineNumber, -1, -1, 0, true, newAttrMap);

        oldBreakpoint.delete();
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```